# How to set default path in apache (xampp)

Tags: php, apache, localhost

Whenever, i open localhost, it is opened as http://localhost/dashboard/. But i want when i open localhost (http://localhost/) in browser, all the list of files and directories will be show. Please anyone can tell me, how to do this.

Comment: Just delete all files in the htdocs folder...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content under `/dashboard` to be available at the root on `http://localhost`, you need to point your site's webroot to that directory, so it's the entry point for your web server.

Open `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` in a text editor of your choice and find

`<Directory "/var/www">`

edit the path to point to your dashboard, something like that:

`<Directory "/var/www/dashboard">`

as final step you need to restart your apache2

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: My directory path is \xampp\htdocs\.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if installation of WAMPP/LAMPP/XAMPP stack software (Windows/ Linux) is a fresh one.

If so, in this cause it is happening due to a statement in index.php (automatically created file during installation) file which is in root folder of the fresh installation of wampp/lampp/xampp stack.

You can simply remove/rename/ replace this index.php file or comment the following lines in index.php

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
} else {
    $uri = 'http://';
}
//$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
exit;
```

If it is not the cause try these things in depends on your os/server

1)[create virtual host Windows xampp](https://medium.com/d6-digital/create-virtual-host-for-apache-on-windows-10-by-using-xampp-8664b0427567)

2)[create virtual host apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

3)[create virtual host Lamp Linux distributions](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/configuration/configure-custom-application/)